# React: Setting useState() hook clears out input fields?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Whenever I set a state in my React app, it clears out my inputs (check box, numbers). Here's a very barebones version that illustrates the issue.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const [dummy, setDummy] = useState(false);

  function handleMint() {
    setDummy((dummy) => !dummy);
  }

  const MintBTN = () => (
    <div>
      <div>
        <input className="form-control" type="number" max="20" min="1" />
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <button onClick={handleMint}>mint</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
  return <MintBTN />;
}
```

You can try it out yourself. Add numbers and click the check box and hit mint. Whamo-bamo, your inputs magically disappear.

https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-buck-6g6oh?file=/src/App.js:0-499

I figure there's something I'm doing wrong that I just don't see yet. I need to be able to click the button or do an onChange event for the inputs without them clearing out. For some reason setting state is also making my page styles freak out. Not sure what's going on. Some of my key dependencies if those are helpful. Thanks.

```
"react": "^17.0.2",
"webpack": "^4.19.1"
```

Comment: Well when you change the dummy state, the component re-renders. React doesn't remember variable values between renders. If you want the input value to persist. Make it a controlled component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you set a state (`setDummy`), the component is rerendered and will reset you're inputs because they are `uncontrolled`. You need to make them `controlled` by using state hooks for those inputs.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const [dummy, setDummy] = useState(false);
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);

  function handleMint() {
    setDummy((dummy) => !dummy);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <input
          className="form-control"
          type="number"
          max="20"
          min="1"
          value={number}
          onChange={e => setNumber(e.target.value)}
        />
        <div>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={checked}
            onChange={e => setChecked(e.target.checked)}
          />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <button onClick={handleMint}>mint</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Notice the `value` and `checked` properties. They are being set by the hook value on each render. Now, notice the `onChange` property. Each time you interact with the input it will update the hook value and rerender the component. By letting React manage the `value` and `checked` properties, it will save the values of the inputs in each hook.

Take a look at [Controlled Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) and [State Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

#### Update

Removed MintBTN function as [Nicholas Tower](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3794812/nicholas-tower) pointed out

Comment: Thanks Michael. I did something similar before I stripped my code down, but this causes another issue with focus I was trying to avoid. It might be easier to see for yourself. I copied your code to codesandbox. If you try to enter a value into the number field that's more than one digit (22) or click the up arrow more than once, the focus jumps out of the field. It's easier to understand if you see it. https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-carlos-1oovr?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Right. See @Nicholas Tower's answer. I updated the code in my response. Just return the JSX in the component without creating and calling a function.

Answer (score -1):

You are creating the MintBTN component *inside* of your App component. This does not work. Every time App renders, you create a brand new type of component. It may have the same text as the previous one, but it's a new type, so react needs to unmount the old one, and mount a new one, which resets the values of stored in any dom elements, and resets any react state.

Instead, create the component once outside of app.

```
export default function App() {
  const [dummy, setDummy] = useState(false);

  function handleMint() {
    setDummy((dummy) => !dummy);
  }

  return <MintBTN onClick={handleMint} />;
}

const MintBTN = ({ onClick }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <input className="form-control" type="number" max="20" min="1" />
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <button onClick={handleMint}>mint</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I don't know who downvoted you. Your answer was helpful, thanks. I gave the other guy the checkmark because his answer is more directly accurate to my individual question, but I wanted to thank you.